# Homebrew Mongodb install

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I just installed MongoDB with homebrew per the official instructions here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ and it also installed mysql, php, and nginx and when I start mongodb, it starts all those services as well (but does not stop them when I stop mongodb btw). Why? Are these other services required by mongodb? I only wanted to use it for a local python script.

```
==> Upgrading 16 dependents of upgraded formulae:
```

Here is the full brew output: https://pastebin.com/zXug1uLh

Comment: I'm surprised that `mysql`, `php`, and `nginx` are installed following the MongoDB install instructions.  You don't need them to run MongoDB.  At which install step were these other apps installed?

Comment: Not sure. I updated the op with the full output.

Comment: I don't know why the package requires all those dependencies.  Perhaps the authors want to install a wide-ranging development environment rather than just MongoDB and it's several tools - not something I would want, but then I don't do any development on a Mac.  Perhaps there's a `brew` command that will only start the MongoDB server.